# Induced EMF and rotating magnets/wires

Tags: electromagnetism

I have a question regarding induced emf's.
The first picture is of a wire/coil rotating inside a uniform magnetic field. I understand the mathematical and physical explanation of faraday's law, therefore I can expect zero emf when field lines are perpendicular to the yellow area (the first position on the left of the photo).

[image]

However I have a problem understading a different case: a magnet that is rotating next to a coil as shown in the picture below. This is the kind of thing to be found in some motorcycle stators etc. The picture below (in addition to other sources that I stumbled upon), states that when the magnet is perpendicular to the base of the coil there is a current flowing, in contradition to the first picture!
Is there a different analysis for the second case? If I am missing something I would be glad to get an explanation regarding how to approach different coil/magnet settings so I won't get confised. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Do you know *why* the EMF is zero when the loop is perpendicular?   What makes the current run when the loop is parallel?

Comment: The emf equals zero when the loop is perpendicular because we get the maximum flux there, so the rate of change of flux would be 0. However my problem is with the second image I posted that is why I posted this question in the first place.

Comment: When you rotate the magnet, the flux lines out of the magnet cross through the coil.  Spinning the magnets changes the flux density through the coil.  When the north pole passes by the coil.  Flux lines enter the coil.  When the south pole passes by the coil.  Flux lines exit the coil.  The strength and number of flux lines entering or exiting the coil varies depending on how fast or slow the magnet is spun.  The equation for EMF is based on Lenz's law.  Try picturing the flux lines from the magnet while the magnet spins.  Does this help? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenz's_law

Comment: When I said strength or number of flux lines, I meant rate of change of flux lines through the coil.  You can also look up how brushless DC motors work.  BLDC's work off the same principle.

Comment: Thankd for the clarification. Found this older thread - it answered what I was looking for. https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/691876/emf-induced-in-solenoid-by-rotating-magnet

Comment: Does this answer your question? [EMF induced in solenoid by rotating magnet](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/691876/emf-induced-in-solenoid-by-rotating-magnet)